# ReadtheDocs config for setup.py installation

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm trying to automatically import a project from Github into ReadtheDocs. When creating the documentation it is failing due to a missing dependency. I've tried adding the setup.py installation in the config, but am running into the following:

- **Problem in your project's configuration. Invalid "python.install.0": .readthedocs.yml: "path" or "requirements" key is required**

Current Configuration yaml:

```
# Required
version: 2

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py

# Optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF and ePub
formats: all

# Optionally set the version of Python and requirements required to build your docs
python:
  version: 3.6
  install:
    - method: setuptools
    - path: .
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue just now, and eventually figured out that the YAML declaration is wrong. It should not be:

```yaml
python:
  version: 3.6
  install:
    - method: setuptools
    - path: .
```

This defines two entries in `python.install`, the first one containing only the `method` key set to `setuptools`, and the second one containing only the `path` key set to `.`. They have nothing to do with each other semantically, and so readthedocs complains about the first entry missing that `path` key. Instead, use:

```yaml
python:
  version: 3.6
  install:
    - method: setuptools
      path: .
```

This now defines `python.install` to be a list with exactly one entry, `python.install.0`, that has both required keys. And so readthedocs started accepting my config after I did this one-character deletion.

Yet another example of YAML being less intuitive than one would like.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to find an answer that leverage the pre-existing setup.py file, but was able to get it working with a requirements.txt file. The relevant portion is the **install** portion of the **python** section in the *readthedocs.yml* file (seen below).

Inside the requirements.txt file I simply copied the install requirements section from the setup.py.

```
# Required
version: 2

# Build documentation in the docs/ directory with Sphinx
sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py

# Optionally build your docs in additional formats such as PDF and ePub
formats: all

# Optionally set the version of Python and requirements required to build your docs
python:
  version: 3.6
  install:
    - requirements: docs/requirements.txt
```